# In Mario and Luigi Superstar Saga, what do the different lvlup statistics actually give you?

Tags: mario-superstar-saga

When you level up, you can choose to increase one of the following attributes:

- HP
- BP (Bros Points?)
- POW
- DEF
- SPEED
- STACHE

I would like to know how each of these stats affect your character.

Answer (score 4):

HP - Hit Points - this is basically your health. Higher number = more health.

BP - Bros Points - you use these for special moves/attacks (they involve the participation of both Mario and Luigi, which is why they are called Bros. Points.) Higher number = the ability to do more or stronger moves.

POW - your power, or the strength of your attacks. Higher number = stronger attacks that do more damage.

DEF - the strength of your defense. Higher number, higher defense ability, lowers the damage that you take.

SPEED - Decides who will take the first turn in battle. Higher number - that character is more likely to get to attack first.

STACHE - this affects both the prices of things in stores AND your chances of doing a Lucky Hit in battle. A higher number means you get a better discount in stores, and you are more likely to do a Lucky Hit in a battle.

Comment: Side note (since Community bumped this anyway): The less recently you've increased a stat, the higher the numbers it will have on the wheel.  Recently spinned ones will have mostly 1s and 2s with a few 3s, less recently spinned ones will have 1s-3s in fairly even proportions, about half as many 4s as 3s, and a few 5s.